# creating a switch between two html contents (with a click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
$(document).on('click','a.show_usr_dtl',function(){
    if(!html_1){var html_1 = $(this).html();}
    var html_2 = get_html_2();//get_html2() brings the content for html_2 through an ajax call, no problem with this
    if(($(this).prop('expansion') == 0) || typeof $(this).prop('expansion') == 'undefined' ){
        $(this).html(html_2);
        $(this).prop('expansion',1);
    } else {
        $(this).html(html_1);
        $(this).prop('expansion',0);
    }
 });
```

As I said in the subject this code should create a switch between two contents for the a.show_usr_dtl element. When the page loads this element has some content, when I click on the element this content is assigned to var html_1 and I want to switch (i.e. the a.show_usr_dtl element must have) html_2 content. I use the property 'expansion' as a flag.
I don't know I don't get what I want.

Comment: I solved it!!!  On the second line I changed to:    if(typeof html_1 == 'undefined'){html_1 = $(this).html();}  I didn't know the var operator resets the variable.  QUESTION: Am I correct with the last sentence?

Comment: I have another problem related to this code, and I have created a jsfiddle you can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/ciroxxx/36ft9/1/    I hope it's clear what I am trying to reach. If you click on the second element multiple times I have the switch working. Then if you click on the first element of the list it switches with the second element while it should switch with the other first element. It's complicated because it works with ajax calls

Comment: I would probably do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/36ft9/3